# Использование наследованного класса

Tags: c++

Есть заголовочный файл test.h в котором хранится абстрактный класс TestABC, а также test.cpp в котором хранится класс Test, наследованный от абстрактного. Как в main.cpp достать класс Test? Я сделал #include "test.h" но не могу использовать класс Test.

Comment: `#include"test.cpp"` - почти шутка. Если определение класса не секретное, то это определение заносите в другой хедер.

Comment: ну почему, можно же просто `class Test;` в main.cpp написать. Правда поиспользовать - это отдельная тема

Comment: По моему автор путает позднее связывание с  неизвестным типом.

Comment: или пытается сделать фабрику.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать функцию/фабрику её объявить в test.h, а реализовать в test.cpp. Тогда её можно вызывать будет в main.cpp. Реализация примерно такая:
где-то файл test.h

```
TestABC* makeTest(<тут параметры могут быть нужные>);
```

где-то файл test.cpp

```
TestABC* makeTest(<тут параметры могут быть нужные>) {
   return new Test(<тут параметры используются>)
}
```

где-то файл main.cpp

```
TestABC* pTest = makeTest(<параметры для Test>);
p->methodTestABC();
...
delete p;
```